# Is there a visual c++ predefined preprocessor macro that lets you know when the compiler is optimizing

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-optimization, predefined-macro

I would like to be able to do something like this using visual c++ compiler (vc12):

```
// If we have compiled with O2
#ifdef _O2_FLAG_
bool debug_mode = false;

// If we are in dirty slow non optimized land
#else
bool debug_mode = true;
#endif
```

But I cannot find a predefined macro for this purpose.

**Context:**

The debug_mode flag is used like:

```
if (!debug_mode && search_timer->seconds_elapsed() > 20) {
   return best_result_so_far;
}
```

The problem being that in a debug instance that I step through this constantly fails and bombs me out because strangely it takes me a lot longer to step through the code than the CPU normally goes through it :-)

If there is some underlying clock that pauses when debug does that would also solve my problem. Currently I am using the difference between two calls to std::chrono::high_res_clock::now().

EDIT:

In response to several comments explaining why I don't want to do what I want to do, I should perhaps reword the question as simply: Is there an equivalent of gcc's `__optimize__` in cl?

Comment: Even if it did exist, the preprocessor can't tell you that the compiler *will* optimize a translation unit (say if no optimization can be done), only that it *may*

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way. You need to improve your debugging skills (e.g. use trace points instead of break points, etc.).

Comment: Use a compiler switch to check for debug mode. Pretty much every IDE out there has the possibility to set debug and release mode, with different compiler options.

Comment: It is worth noting that detecting optimization in your code very likely could prevent the optimization, since C++ optimization rules require that for an optimization to be allowed in any given case, it must be verifiable at the code-level that it produces the same result as the unoptimized version.  If you have code that is conditional on optimization, this may prevent verifying that the optimization produces the same result.

Comment: An optimizing compiler will anyway remove `!debugmode &&` if it is `true`, or it will remove entire if-statement if this expression is `false`. You cannot reliably land in safe place with such flag (if it were possible). Better is just to use `Debug` as conditional compilation.

Comment: @Ajay /Zi is always on, because the profiler needs it, so unfortunately `Debug` is useless to me. I am aware that if the relevant preprocessor definition existed I could just surround the `if` statement with `ifdefs` for the same effect. What I want to do is switch between debugging and profiling modes with minimum effort (ie the presence of `/O2` on the compile line) which would be simple using gcc's `__optimize__`, hence the question of whether cl had something like this.

Comment: Assuming your debug builds have /RTC turned on, you can check for `__MSVC_RUNTIME_CHECKS`. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/rtc-run-time-error-checks?view=msvc-170

Answer (score 4):

You could use either `_DEBUG` or `NDEBUG` to detect the debug configuration. This technically doesn't mean the same thing as the optimization flag, but 99% of the time this should suffice.

Another option would be to add a preprocessor definition to the project yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to build with debug information most times I build with optimization as well for the profiler to work properly or I would have done this. Seems like visual c++ gives very few macros like this compared to gcc. I wondered if I had missed a nice web page full of them somewhere.